# Connect to FTP and extract ZIP with PHP?

Tags: php, ftp

I have a project idea, but I don't know much about it. I want to extract my Zip file on FTP with PHP. I tried a few functions but I was not successful. Can you help me?

The codes I have right now;

```
if ($_POST){
    //ftp serverımızı, kullanıcı adı ve şifremizi yazıyoruz. 

    $ftpserver = $_POST['ftp_host'];
    $ftpuser  = $_POST['ftp_kadi'];
    $ftppass  = $_POST['ftp_sifresi'];
     
    //POST metodu ile dosyamızı çekiyoruz.  
    $kaynakdosya = "./minecraft.zip";
    $hedefdosya = "./minecraft.zip";  
     
    //ftp_connect ile ftp serverımıza bağlanıyoruz    
    $baglanti = ftp_connect($ftpserver);  
     
    //kullanııcı bilgilerimiz ile giriş yapıyoruz.  
    $giris = ftp_login($baglanti, $ftpuser, $ftppass);  
     
    //bağlantı ve girişin olumlu olup olmadığını kontrol ediyoruz.  
    if ((!$baglanti) || (!$giris)) {  
        echo "Ftp bağlantısı sağlanamadı";  
        die;  
    } else {  
        echo "Ftp'ye bağlanıldı<br>";  
    }  
 
    //ftp_put fonksiyonu ile dosyamızı yüklüyoruz.  
 
    $yukle = ftp_put($baglanti,$hedefdosya, $kaynakdosya, FTP_BINARY);  


    //yüklenip yüklenemdiğini kontrol ediyoruz  
    if (!$yukle) {  
        echo "Dosya Yüklenemiyor";  
    } else {  
        echo "Dosya Yüklendi";  
    }  
    ftp_close($baglanti);  
}
```

It connects to the server first, then throws the file and cannot handle the extraction while it needs to be extracted. I would be really happy if you could help. I'm a little new :)

Comment: For this you'd need a shell on the ftp server.

Comment: Could you give more detailed information? I am looking for the answer to this question, obviously how to do this with PHP. I'm using google translate because I'm a Turkish person, I'm sorry if I get it wrong.

Comment: Ok, just lets say it is impossible (usually you don't get ftp + shell due to security reasons)

Comment: If we can remove it normally, why should we not? If I try to extract by typing a URL, can you succeed? Because I know many people who do this, but unfortunately I have no proximity.

Answer (score 0):

Extract zip with php like this with ZipArchive:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zippedfile= "minecraft.zip";//you can change location/name
if ($zip->open($zippedfile) !== TRUE) {
        echo 'Something went wrong';
} else {
    $zip->extractTo('.');//you can change location
    $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have to do this in ftp when I connect to FTP.

Comment: So please upload php file with my code via FTP and get url of this file for example with file_get_contents. It extract Your ZIP.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know how to pray to you. For those who could not, I sent 2 different files, as your friend said.

Comment: Prays are unnecessary :D Simply mark as helpful :)